# Form Class in J2ME Polish

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I was just wondering if the Form Class in the J2ME polish api for GUI development maintains a list of references to the Items that are appended to it.
The Form that I am using has a number of text fields appended to it 
using the following code.

`form.append(new TextField(...))` and then all this goes into a for loop.

How do I refer to these TextFields??

form is a reference to an existing form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is interested ... the answer is yes.

You can use the `Form` `get( int itemNum )` method to retrieve the `Item` appended at position `itemNum`.

The `size()` method will tell you how many items have been appended for the Form.